# Binding WebBrowser.DocumentText to a BindingSource won't update

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a BindingSource with it's DataSource property set to a DataSet. I then have several controls that are bound to different columns of tables in the DataSet.

```
bsStatus.DataSource = statusDS;

dgvStatus.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", bsStatus, "Status");
lblBRId.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsStatus, "Status.BorrowerAccount");
lblCBId.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsStatus, "Status.CoBorrowerAccount");
// MORE CONTROL BINDINGS
webBrowser1.DataBindings.Add("DocumentText", bsStatus, "Status.ScriptLog");
```

This all works just fine on loading. My controls are populated with the correct values. The problem comes when updating the 'statusDS' DataSet. Most controls are just fine. The TextBox and DataGridView controls update just fine when the source DataSet is changed.

The problem is that the WebBrowser.DocumentText property isn't updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized I had set

```
WebBrowser.AllowNavigation = false
```

Setting it back to true solved the issue.